# How can an inverter transfer energy to the power network?

Tags: inverter, mains

It is possible to use an inverter to transfer energy from home made produced energy to the main power network. It is not clear to me how this can be achieved. What type of load appear to be the power supply network? What are the strategy to have the power flowing from the inverter to the the load and not vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grid-tied inverters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid-tie_inverter) do exactly what you're describing. Adding power to the grid is far from trivial, and isn't something that a few paragraphs of explanation can fully cover. People have spent decades on this sort of research.

The best way I've heard to describe the grid is 'infinite sink' and 'infinite source'.

An inverter carefully and accurately monitors the phase of the grid voltage and keeps itself in agreement, else the grid will try and push/pull far more current than the inverter can produce. (Mechanical generators have to be similarly synchronized else the grid will correct the generators, sometimes catastrophically)

It also must detect grid interruptions (islanding) and disconnect itself such that linesmen working on an isolated section of grid don't get electrocuted.

Comment: Great to know it is not trivial, I was worried my question was to simple, but really I can't figure out. I will try to learn from the source you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an inverter can be used to transfer energy to the main power network. I'm not about to answer how an inverter works but if you meant how can power transfer be achieved, here is a quote from Mother Nature network -

Most standard utility meters can measure the flow of energy in either direction. The meter spins forward when electricity is flowing from the utility to the customer and spins backward when power is flowing from the customer to the utility. Check with your power company to be sure you have the correct inverter to safely operate your alternative energy system.

This should explain that the strategy is automatic providing you have a meter capable of reverse flow

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually the question is: how?

Comment: @FelicePollano - please be clearer about your question. How.... what?

Comment: How what, exactly? In the same way as any other generator: it pushes charge through a transformer inducing current and voltage on the line. Current then flows from the inverter to the nearest actual load in the network, usually in some nearby building.